# Add ctrl functionality to alt_l (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

Since my ctrl buttons are broken i want to transfer ctr functionality to alt_l.
More specifically i want alt+c, alt+v and others ctrl key combinations work for alt_l and at the same time preserve some alt combinations like alt+tab.

`xmodmap` function looks like it can solve it but i saw only examples of how to swap key buttons

```
remove Lock = Caps_Lock
remove Control = Control_L
keysym Control_L = Caps_Lock
keysym Caps_Lock = Control_L
add Lock = Caps_Lock
add Control = Control_L
```

or transfer functionality without preserving button's base functions.

How can i make my alt_l button work simultaneously as alt and ctrl?

P.S. Excuse my english

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run the commands as below:

1. `xmodmap -e "remove mod1 = Alt_L"`
2. `xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_L = Control_L"`
3. `xmodmap -e "add Control = Control_L"`

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770U:~$ xmodmap -e "remove mod1 = Alt_L"
pratap@i7-4770U:~$ xmodmap -e "keysym Alt_L = Control_L"
pratap@i7-4770U:~$ xmodmap -e "add Control = Control_L"
pratap@i7-4770U:~$
```

Expalation:

1. removes the modifier from Alt_L
2. Alt_L becomes Control_L with out modifer
3. adds the modifier Control to Control_L keysym

these changes will not persist after a logout or reboot..

to make these changes permanent..

add below content to `~/.xmodmaprc` file

```
remove mod1 = Alt_L
keysym Alt_L = Control_L
add Control = Control_L
```

and add this command to startup applications

`xmodmap /home/user/.xmodmaprc` #change user with your user name

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Now i sholud just add some necessary shortcuts with ctrl to make them work with alt button pressed, right?

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/@damko/a-simple-humble-but-comprehensive-guide-to-xkb-for-linux-6f1ad5e13450) is quite good guide to all this stuff. I'll just leave it here.